# Date change format (Days Become month and Month become Days) when I pass it into a variable

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to put into a variable a French date : `"dd/mm/yyyy"`

But, sometimes the days and month swap for exemple :

**07/02/2019** become **02/07/2019** .

This seems working with some date but some times month + days swap.

To handle this I tried this formula :

`MyDate = DateValue(Format(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Compteur, 49).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy"))`

When I put

`MyDate = DateValue(Format(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Compteur, 49).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy"))` This seems working, but i don't understand the logic : Is it really working or is this just luck.

But the error is still here, Am I doing something wrong here ?

Else If there is no solution to my problem, I would try to use an R1C1 formula like below :

`Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Tableau3,MATCH(C" & Compteur & ",Tableau3[Matricule],0),49),"""")")`

But this seems not working I don't understand why, Basicly this formula should search an ID value from Column "C" into an other sheet in a Tab's Column called `Tableau3[Matricule]` then output the value of the 49 Columns of the cells where the ID is The ID of the other sheet.

The error of this fomula is `2015` so **#VALUE**

**NOTE :** The Value which is saved into `MyDate` is selected in a cell set as date format and then pasted into an other sheet with a cell also set as date.

Kindest regard.

Comment: If the cell contains an actual date value, not a text representation of a date, you should just refer to its `Value` property.

Comment: @Rory So that mean that I must delete `DateValue()` ?

Comment: And `Format`. You don't need either for a real date.

Comment: @Rory , this didn't solve my issue , I will listen you and let datevalue and format deleted. Do you have any idea of what can be my issue ?

Comment: The format of the date on your worksheet is irrelevant to **storing** that value in VBA, so long as the date on the worksheet is not a text string.  But if you change it into a text string, as you are doing with the `Format` function, and then write that text string back to the worksheet, you have the potential to screw things up. What is your windows regional short date setting?

Comment: Is `MyDate` declared as a `Date` type? Do your cells contain actual dates (they will align to the right of the cell by default) or text (aligns to the left)?

Comment: @RonRosenfeldI think that It is french format date (I am from Paris). Where can I double check ?I Tried to set the date format as String in my excel and this still doesn't change :  `43739` become `43475`. I really don't get it... But if I copy and past with my end the date stays at the right formart so days and month don't change...

Comment: @Rory `MyDate` is declared as a `String` thats why I used `DateValue()`

Comment: Declare `MyDate` as a **Date**

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I did it seems working, Silly error indeed I am confused. Thought that `DateValue()` would work even if `MyVar` was a `String`

Comment: Yes, it does. But without knowing exactly what you are doing and how you are doing it, I would guess that with all the apparently unnecessary data type conversions between your worksheet and your VBA code, somewhere the US-centricity of VBA has probably resulted in the issue, especially when you feed Datevalue an ambiguous string.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thats why I am not friendly with Date in VBA ;) it's a nice source of Mistake if we don't double check after executing macro. For exemple my macro gave me full error and I just solve the issue now thanks to you and rory. Thanks for all

Comment: Dates can be confusing, especially in VBA.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld They are, Have a nice day and again thank you I was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe you can use something of this sort.**

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Compteur, 49)

MyDate = format(Month(.Value) & "/" & Day(.Value) & "/" & Year(.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")

End With
```

It will always give you the right Format.

---

**In Excel**

For the Dates you see are wrong as you described. Use the Formula `=DATE(YEAR(G14),DAY(G14),MONTH(G14))`

It will convert:

[image]

Actually the `Date` formula takes 3 argument, `Year,Month,Day` but in your case you have Month as Day and Day as Month, so we used `Year,Day,Month` to covert the Dates.

Comment: that still doesn't work I think that vba read date only as UK format : mm/dd/yyyy so he always thinks that the day is the month and the month is the day that can explain when I use format("mm/dd/yyyy") it seems displaying the good date...

Comment: See Excel Stores Date as Numbers. The Display Format is however you can choose. So todays date stored in Excel would be a Number `43661`, tomorrow would be 1 + 43661. So to get around the Display format, you can use the formula in Answer, that will fetch the correct Day, Month, Year from the Displayed date and give you the correct date.

Comment: Source data `43739` and data stored int var : `43475` , Hope you How to Solve this issue, I feel like I am the only one which have issues with date. If you can't help me more can you please UpVote this post so someone will maybe help me to solve this issue ... Thanks for your time and consideration

Comment: does it work with vba ? `Evaluate("=DATE(YEAR(G14),DAY(G14),MONTH(G14))")` Regards

Comment: I have also edited the Formula for VBA, In the Answer. The First Part

Comment: As I said the VBA answer is not working as excepted : `01/10/2019` become `10/01/2019` or with number : `43739` become `43475` but I don't understand it seems that vba can't read french date format ...

Comment: Okay. Maybe someone else can Help you. Though you can see how the formula is working and mend it according to your requirement. :)